# In Settings.settings, default Provider does not support user-specific settings?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, settings.settings

I have this project in VS2010, MVC2 written in C#. My problem is that it doesn't seem like I can have user-specific settings, only application-specific, which I then can't update from code which is sort of useless to me at the moment..

Any ideas on this? I mean, I don't get any errors or anything like that. In the Settings-dialog I can add new settings just fine, but there's no drop-down in the "Scope" column, it just defaults to "Application" and stays that way.. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Ok the "Provider"-property of each setting-entry is empty (not sure if this is default behaviour or not usually?), but if I enter a value there I can then choose between "Application" and "User". However, that would require me to write my own Provider, which I'd prefer not having to do.. Is there no-one who have experienced this before or have any ideas at all?

Comment: I gave up and wrote my own SettingsProvider... Maybe that's the way you have to do it to be able to use User-scoped settings (haven't seen it mentioned in any examples though), but if it isn't and anyone has any ideas, please share!